# Laravel service manifest

Tags: php, laravel

From my point of understanding, Laravel besides provider list in **app/app.php**, generate a **service manifest**  which is a kind of proxy. It is responsible for loading only necessary providers for a given request.
e.g. if we don't use **View service provider**(even it is registered) on a request, Laravel will not load it.

Am I right ?

Answer (score 3):

Kind of yes and no. What Laravel does, as far as I know is inspects the contents of the `providers` key in `config/app.php`. The for each one of those, it instantiates the service provider class. It then checks whether the `deferred` property is set to true.

If it is not, the class is registered and booted in the normal way.

If `deferred` is set to true, the class is kind put on hold until it's needed. The contents of the `provides` array is inspected to see what IoC keys are registered in this class, then as soon as one of those needs to be registered, the service provider is registered and booted like any other.

The service manifest in the storage directory simply caches the output of this service provider inspection so it doesn't have to do it every request (i.e. so it doesn't have to instantiate and check `deferred` and `provides` - the non-deferred classes still have to be instantiated, registered and booted regardless of this).

I'm not sure under what circumstances this cache is 'invalidated' though. Presumably when the actual contents of the `providers` config key changes, but maybe it's able to also do checking on the SPs without instantiating them too.

As for non-deferred service providers - it would be right to say that if a given IoC service is not used, then it's never instantiated. But that is a different matter to the service manifest as far as I know.

Comment: alexrussell - thanks.I did vote for your answer just because you were close and you did a hard job trying to explain this to me. Let me teach you something :) - I just read a code. Every provider has a registered event that listens if it is called. So deffered simply means that provider is listenting for events.